# Split text file by =

Tags: text-processing, text-editor

I have a bunch of .dat files (about 1000) in separate folders. each of them has some kind of data  like below :

```
Carreau Poseuille Flow

Velocity in lattice units: u=0.00210431
Reynolds number:           Re=5.30287
Carreau number:            Cu=10
Lattice resolution:        N=252
Extent of the system:      lx=1
Extent of the system:      ly=1
Extent of the system:      lz=1
Grid spacing deltaX:       dx=0.00396825
Time step deltaT:          dt=8.35045e-06
Exponent:                  n=1
Zero viscosity:            nu0=0.1
Inf viscosity:             nuInf=0
Zero Omega:                omega0=1.25
Inf  Omega:                omegaInf=2
Lambda:                    lambda=1.19754e+06
time dependancy factor:                    TDfactor=1
```

I want to split this text and remove anything by the left side of = ; which means I only need numbers in a column. I appreciate any suggestion.

many thanks;
Elahe

Answer (score 1):

You can cut at `=` and select second column:

```
< input-file cut -d = -f2 > output-file
```

See `man cut` for more details about `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cut` at `=` and be done.

```
cut -d= -f 2 input_file >output_file
```

Read `man cut`.